# Initialize 2d array of chars

Tags: c, arrays

Im trying to initialize 2d array of chars with this ode

```
int x=4;
int y=4;
char plg[x][y]={{"o","o","o","o"},{"o","o","o","o"},{"o","o","o","o"},{"o","o","o","o"}};
```

but this piece of code throws error `error: excess elements in char array initializer|` i was searching for a while and everything says this is the rigth method how to do 2d char array.  Why does it throw error?

Comment: did you try `'o'` instead of `"o"`?

Comment: VLA (Variable Length Array) can't have initializer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"this is a string"
```

and

```
'o' /* this is a character */
```

Answer (score 5):

In C you cannot use dynamic expressions as array sizes for global variables. It is possible for local variables since the C99 Standard, but these arrays known as `VLA` cannot be initialized.

For your purpose, you must specify the size directly with literal constants or constant expressions.  You can use macros to increase readability, but it is a bad idea to `#define x 4` as short identifiers like `x` may be used elsewhere in your program and will be substituted as well, leading to obscure bugs.

You cannot initialize the 2D array of `char` with a string for each individual `char`, you can either use character literals this way:

```
char plg[4][4] = {
    {'o','o','o','o'},
    {'o','o','o','o'},
    {'o','o','o','o'},
    {'o','o','o','o'}
};
```

Or you can use string literals to initialize the last level of the array:

```
char plg[4][4] = {"oooo", "oooo", "oooo", "oooo" };
```

Note that although you can elide the inner braces with `char` literal initializers this way:

```
char plg[4][4] = {'o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o' };
```

It is not possible to coalesce string initializers this way:

```
char plg[4][4] = { "oooooooooooooooo" }; // warning: initializer-string for char array is too long
```

The syntax above only initializes the first subarray with `'o'`s, leaving the remaining 3 initialized with `'\0'`s

If you *really* need for the sizes to be dynamic, you will need to initialize the array some other way:

```
void myfunc(int x, int y) {
    char plg[x][y];
    int scores[x][y];

    // you can initialize char arrays this way
    memset(plg, 'o', sizeof(plg));

    // you need a loop for other types
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            scores[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

You still need to be careful with this feature: you must check user input a avoid allocating too much data in automatic storage (aka *on the stack*).  Sufficiently large or possibly negative values of `x` or `y` will invoke undefined behavior. Only small values should be allowed, typically less than 256.  For a more general solution, you will need to allocate `plg` from the heap.

Comment: This won't work with standard C. You can't specify rows, and cols as variables - need #define

Comment: @artm: Indeed, you cannot do that for global variables, but it is possible for local variables since C99. I corrected the answer with extra precision.

Comment: "It is possible for local variables since the C99 Standard." Do you mean we can declare `plg[x][y]` if `x` and `y` are local variables? I doubt that it's true even with c99.

Comment: @artm: you *can* define local arrays with variable sizes, including multi-dimensional ones.  Yet these VLAs cannot have an initializer.

Comment: yeah but 2d initializer is exactly what he asks for, it cannot be done with variables as the sizes.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define N_ROWS 4
#define N_COLS 4
```

you have to replace " with ' (single) cause it's not string but chars:

```
char plg[N_ROWS][N_COLS]={{'o','o','o','o'},{'o','o','o','o'},{'o','o','o','o'},{'o','o','o','o'}};
```

moreover the initializers have to be definied during compile time not during runtime otherwise it would be a dynamic array for which you need to allocate memory manually.

Comment: This won't work with standard C. You can't specify `rows`, and `cols` as variables - need #define

Comment: I changed my code just when you downvoted. would you please undo it.

Comment: but in this case i cant dynamicly change value of N_ROWS and N_COLS or can i? I want set the size of array by user Input of rows/collums

Comment: @user3706129 - see my answer which you can use to accept input for rows/cols.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you need to define `rows` and `cols` when declaring a matrix, such as:

```
#define N_ROWS 4
#define N_COLS 4

char plg[N_ROWS][N_COLS]={{'o','o','o','o'},{'o','o','o','o'},{'o','o','o','o'},{'o','o','o','o'}};
```

---

Now if you need `rows` and `cols` as input variables, you need to dynamically allow the array. For example,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int x = 4;
int y = 4;
char **plg = malloc(sizeof(char *) * x);
int i = 0;
for( i = 0; i < x; i++ )
{
    plg[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (y + 1));    // +1 for NULL terminator
}

for( i = 0; i < x; i++ )
{
    strcpy( plg[i], "oooo" );
    printf( "%s \n", plg[i] );
}
```

Comment: Using the array indexing syntax `plg[i]` is probably more readable than the equivalent `*(plg + i)`.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char) * (y + 1)) ` can be simplified to `malloc(y+1)` due to `sizeof(char)` being `1`. same for `malloc(sizeof(char *) * x)`

Comment: I know `sizeof(char) = 1`; but normally in `malloc` code, you should make `sizeof` explicit for the type (`sizeof(int8)` is 1 as well).