# Initializing a Peg Solitaire Board in C

Tags: c

I am trying to initialize and display a Simple T board in Solitaire Peg. It looks something like this.

```
-----
-@@@-
--@--
--@--
-----
```

My code does this, but not in a way a programmer should. That being said, what I mean is that I just use for loops to put @s as pegs and - as empty holes.

Is there any better way to initialize a random board?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < T_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        Tboard[0][i] = '-';
        Tboard[4][i] = '-';
    }
    
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Tboard[i][0] = '-';
        Tboard[i][4] = '-';
        Tboard[1][i] = '@';
    }
    
    for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Tboard[i][1] = '-';
        Tboard[i][2] = '@';
        Tboard[i][3] = '-';
    }

    // Output is the T board given above
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33843350/2757035

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Should I delete my post?

Comment: We could perhaps mark it as a duplicate, since although the user asking there had a different problem, the answer I linked (not the accepted one) is a very nice overview of the ways to initialise 2D arrays of characters, and I couldn't quickly find another such answer.